# Install Atom editor on Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-2, ubuntu

Is ist possible to install [Atom](http://atom.io) on a Raspberry Pi 2 running Ubuntu?

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to install Atom on the Raspberry Pi. 
I did it on Ubuntu Mate (but I guess it works the same way with Raspbian).

**Instructions**

1. You got to install some dependencies with the terminal emulator.
   Install all the dependencies:
   `sudo apt-get install build-essential git libgnome-keyring-dev fakeroot  gconf2 gconf-service libgtk2.0-0 libudev1 libgcrypt20 python rpm npm npm-cli apm nodejs`
   Set the python path:
   `npm config set python /usr/bin/python2 -g`
   Install node-gyp:
   `npm install -g node-gyp`
   Note that node-gyp made an issue here, you need to install it also in the project folder, otherwise you will have build errors.
2. Download the source:
   `git clone https://github.com/atom/atom.git`
3. Navigate into the source folder:
   `cd atom`
4. Install node-gyp locally:
   `npm install node-gyp`
5. Build the source:
   `./script/build`
   If this gives you issues try with sudo:
   `sudo ./script/build`
6. If everything builds correctly you will get a folder named "out".
   Now run the install script:
   `sudo script/grunt install`
   This installs atom into the folder "/usr/local/bin"
7. Add the Icon Menu.
   According to your window manager this is different.
   I used mate to add my icon.
   You may check if the system finds the program and the icon automatically, then you don't need to add the item in the menu.
   Otherwise right-click into the main menu.
   Click `edit menu`.
   Select the category where you want to place atom. Maybe use "development".
   Click `add item`.
   Now select the icon. The atom icons are in the folder called "atom/out/icons".
   Name it "atom".
   Command:`/usr/local/share/atom/atom %F`.
   Command: "Atom editor" or whatever you like.

That's it!
Now start atom an see if it is working.
If you run into problems, see the issues below. Otherwise write a comment.

**Issues**

- If you cannot install nodejs use nodejs-legacy instead.
- If the build cannot find node-gyp install it locally (see above).
- If you run into errors starting atom give write acces to the atom folder.
  `sudo chmod 777 -R /usr/local/share/atom/`
  `sudo chmod 777 -R .atom/`

Comment: Installing npm using apt-get landed me with 1.14. `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -`  was the only way I could get it to use a new version.