# Installing Atom text editor on Rasberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I am following the item [Install Atom editor on Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55031/install-atom-editor-on-raspberry-pi)

However, when attempting some of the steps I receive an error.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git libgnome-keyring-dev fakeroot gconf2 gconf-service libgtk2.0-0 libudev1 libgcrypt20 python rpm npm npm-cli apm nodejs Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package npm-cli 
E: Unable to locate package apm

sudo apt-get install build-essential git libgnome-keyring-dev fakeroot gconf2 gconf-service libgtk2.0-0 libudev1 libgcrypt20 python rpm npm npm-cli apm nodejs-legacy Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package npm-cli 
E: Unable to locate package apm
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't find those packages (`apm` and `npm-cli`) because you followed the instructions written for Ubuntu, while using Raspbian.

I suggest you follow the official [build instructions](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/docs/build-instructions/linux.md) for Linux. As you will see, those two packages you're missing are not even required. The official build prerequesities are

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git libgnome-keyring-dev fakeroot rpm libx11-dev libxkbfile-dev npm nodejs
```

I believe you only really need `fakeroot` and `rpm` if you want to create packages for distribution.

Answer (score 5):

#### Update

Official ARM support is still not there yet and is unlikely to come around, as running on low-power devices such as the Raspberry Pi is [apparently out of scope of the main Atom project](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/14279#issuecomment-296839127).

There was at one point [**a functioning ARM fork of Atom**](https://github.com/hypersad/atom-armv7l), but it's gone now.

---

#### <s>You can't run Atom on a Raspberry Pi. (Yet.)</s>

Atom support on ARM systems, such as Raspberry Pi, is [an open issue](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/7822) right now. So far, to my knowledge, nobody succeeded in running it there without major breakages.

From a consumer perspective all you can do now is wait. But if you wish to try to achieve this, you'll have to study Atom's build process, expecting a blocking issue somewhere along the way. Current official instructions obviously won't get you far.

Comment: Thanks, development is still ongoing as of this date. Would be good to check back in from time-to-time.

Comment: sadly, this fork is 404 now ...

Comment: @aGuegu true, the effort seems to have died down entirely :( And the issues have been closed despite not being resolved.

Comment: The fork has since moved or is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully installed & run Atom 1.15.0 on a Raspberry Pi 3B (1GB RAM) over Raspbian Jennie, using the suggestions posted by user hypersad on github at https://github.com/hypersad/atom-armv7l

**There were some minor changes to the sequence suggested there:**

1. *Nodejs* version 8 had previously been installed (and remained installed). (This had removed the installations of nodejs-legacy and nodered that were part of the initial installation.)
2. The installation of *nodejs* 8 also installed *npm*, so this was not required to be installed after *nvm* was used to set the active *nodejs* version to 6.10.2 and, in fact, attempts to install it after activating *nvm* only invoke a comprehensive list of errors.
3. *Git* was not required to be installed as it is part of the initial Raspbarian image.
4. Similarly, *build-essential* and *fakeroot* were already installed.
5. Following the build of Atom, the *atom.firstboot.sh* script was run, as suggested. This did not install Atom but did create the *.atom* directory and loaded a large number of Atom packages. This takes quite a while.
6. Installation was achieved by following the suggestion to create a Debian package and then use that to install Atom (running *dpkg* as root via *sudo*).

Note that Atom will suggest that the *tree-view* 0.214.1 package requires updating. As noted in the above web page, more recent versions will not work with this version of Atom (1.15.0), so don't accept the suggestion.

Cheers, Brian

Comment: the github link is now a 404 :(