# Atom text editor on raspberry pi 4?

Tags: software-installation

I'm looking to install Atom on my Raspberry pi 4. In ARMHF naturally.
I have already tried a lot of solution, but nothing works.
I tried the atom-arhmf.deb from the official github repository and followed: [Installing Atom text editor on Rasberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57456/installing-atom-text-editor-on-rasberry-pi) and [Installing Atom text editor on Rasberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57456/installing-atom-text-editor-on-rasberry-pibut) unfortunately without result .

#### Can someone refer me?

Comment: Can you post any error message you see or explain what is going wrong a bit more please?

Answer (score 0):

I have been affected by Atom problems on my Raspberry Pi 4B too.

I am reposting a question that I submitted to Linux Questions yesterday. Today's reply to that question was about the Package Cloud web site's Raspbian repository possibly being down.

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/apt-get-update-raspberry-pi-4b-debian-10-buster-raspbian-missing-release-file-in-packagecloud-io-atomeditor-dependency-4175675145/

***apt-get update - Raspberry Pi 4B - Debian 10 Buster - raspbian - missing Release file in packagecloud.io AtomEditor dependency?***
Good afternoon (from the UK). This is my first post in Linux Questions.

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B as stated in the Subject, with 4GB RAM, 32 GB SD card.

I had problems with sources.list in /etc/apt - RESOLVED - these were caused by me splitting a line when trying to install VS Code on the Pi.

However, apt-get update does not complete, and I consequently cannot successfully install the GNS3 Network Simulator on the Pi.

**THIS IS MY sources.list file content:**

Code:

deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi

## Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'

deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi

**This is my terminal activity when I tried apt-get update** (as root user; I am still new to Linux computers as opposed to virtualization in Windows, Visual Studio Code):

The problem appears to be with PackageCloud.io. I have been to that site, including the address in red ("The page you were looking for doesn't exist.")

Code:

```
pi sources.list.d
$ sudo su   
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease [15.0 kB]
Ign:3 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/raspbian buster InRelease        
Get:4 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease [23.2 kB]
Hit:5 https://packagecloud.io/headmelted/codebuilds/debian stretch InRelease
Err:6 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/raspbian buster Release 
  404  Not Found [IP: 52.52.201.17 443]
Get:7 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any/main amd64 Packages [30.0 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease [25.1 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main Sources [92.1 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf Packages [327 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/raspbian buster Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

**Contents of /etc/apt**

Code:

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apt# ls
apt.conf.d   listchanges.conf  sources.list    sources.list.save  trusted.gpg~
auth.conf.d  preferences.d     sources.list.d  trusted.gpg    trusted.gpg.d
```

**Contents of /etc/apt/sources.list.d**

Code:

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# ls
AtomEditor_atom.list  atom.list  atom.list.save  gns3.list  headmelted_vscode.list  raspi.list
```

atom.list.save is the result of me repeatedly editing atom.list in the Nano editor in the LX Terminal.

**Text of atom.list**

Code:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main
```

**Text of AtomEditor_atom.list**

```
# this file was generated by packagecloud.io for
# the repository at https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom
```

Code:

```
deb https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/raspbian/ buster main
deb-src https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/raspbian/ buster main

linux
```

Comment: AMD64 is the wrong architecture. The Raspberry Pi is either ARMHF or AARCH64.

Comment: Thank you very much! Thanks to your reply, I have just amended atom.list now to armhf instead of amd64!